# Can I publish my research article in a journal AND as a chapter in a book?

Tags: publications

As I understand you cannot publish your paper in two different journals, I was wondering if the same rule applies to chapters in books.  My research (52 pages long) was summarized into 20 pages to fit into a chapter of a book and in another language (Portuguese).  Now, I would like to publish the same paper (in its entirety) in a journal, rather than a chapter in a book. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: It should be fine. But **do not** claim it as two different publications in your CV.  List it only once, with both references.  Perhaps calling it "summary" in one of the references.

Answer (score 1):

You are phrasing your question in a slightly confusing way. It seems that what you have is a 20 page text that has already appeared in a book, and a 52 page text that you would like to submit to a journal. Is that correct?

In that case, they are hardly "the same paper". Rather, what you seem to be asking is:

> Can I write two different papers (a brief summary for a book and also
> a much longer journal paper) based on the same body of research?

To which the answer is a resounding yes. Of course, the paper is only likely to be accepted if it adds something substantial on top of the 20 page summary paper.

Note that this has nothing to do with one publication being part of a book and the other being in a journal. Your question suggests that you believe that if you tried to publish in a journal the same paper that has already appeared in a book (which is *not* what you are doing), then somehow different rules would apply then when you tried to publish in a journal a paper that has already appeared in another journal, but this is not the case. The difference between a book chapter and a journal paper is not really relevant to the fact that journals will generally not republish texts that have already appeared elsewhere. (At least I am confident that this is how it works for journals that I am familiar with.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that going from journal article to textbook chapter is fairly normal - as long as you hold copyright and the publisher wants to include the chapter there shouldn't be a problem. The goal of a textbook is to present known information to its audience.

Going in the other direction presents some potential issues.

1. If the work has been published in any format (other than some common exceptions such as preprints or theses) a journal might not accept the submission.
2. If it has already been published, you may no longer hold copyright. A derivative work *might* run afoul of some license or copyright agreement.
3. If there is no substantial new info included in the paper, you might have a hard time finding a willing journal even if it's not technically against the publisher's rules and there are no copyright issues.

In your situation, I don't think you can just submit as if the textbook chapter didn't exist. But I don't see any reason not to try to get your work published.  Basically, I think you need to coordinate with journals and your book publisher to ensure that there are not any roadblocks.

Answer (score 0):

Strange question, because a journal article would have to be shorter than a book chapter, it would not be the longer version (at least that's my experience with journals). But if the second publication is an extended version of the first, and particularly, if it is a translation into a different language (as you say) they may count as sufficiently distinct to publish both, in principle. Otherwise, rework the stuff to make it distinct.